# How to find the distance between the two discriptos?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vocabulary(centroids of clusters)in yml file from a set of images.Now i have acquired a new SURF descriptor from an image.Now i would like to check how far or near  this new keypoint descriptor to the vocabulary with some threshold,and save both good and bad matches.Once i have good and bad descriptos how can i mark them on the image as keypoints.I am quite new to opencv.I have gone through knnMatch but it only gives good matches by specifying k.could some one help me by suggestion or sample code.

And here is my sample code

```
  Mat dictionary;
  FileStorage fs("../bin/dictionary1.yml", FileStorage::READ);
  fs["vocabulary"] >> dictionary;
  fs.release();

  std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
  detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
  SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc;
  Mat descriptors1;
  surfDesc.compute(img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors1);
```

i would like to do somethig like this

```
for all image descriptor
 for all vacabulary
   if(dist is less)
     goodmatch
     cvcolor=blue
   else 
     badmatch
     cvcolor=red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Euclidian distance d=sqrt( a1^2+a2^2+...an^2), but in this case it'll be better to use Mahalanobis distance, because it takes into consideration distribution parameters (covariance). But you need to compute covariance for each cluster, which you can get on train phase. You have centers of clusters, you have points for every cluster thats enought for covariance evaluation.

Comment: Thank you.i got an idea now.i will try to implement it.